# AttributeError: '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute 'StringIO'

Tags: python, compression

I am looking for the solution to this error and I checked other similar questions but couldn't find an answer.
I am trying to implement Lempel-Ziv-1978 data compression algorithm and I have that error in my decompression function which is:

def decompresser(stringAdecompresser):

```
from io import StringIO

# creer la dictionnaire
size = 256
dictionnaire = {chr(i): i for i in range(size)}

resultat = StringIO()
w = chr(stringAdecompresser.pop(0))
resultat.write(w)
for k in stringAdecompresser:
    if k in dictionnaire:
        entree = dictionnaire[k]
    else: # k == size:
        entree = w + w[0]


    resultat.write(entree)

    #ajouter dans la dictionnaire
    dictionnaire[size] = w + entree[0]
    size += 1

    w = entree
return resultat.StringIO()
```

and I got:
**File "lz78.py", line 52, in decompresser
  return resultat.StringIO()
AttributeError: '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute 'StringIO'**

Python version: 3.6

Comment: I think you want: `return resultat.getvalue()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `resultat` is already a `StringIO`. Either return that, or, as @mechanical_meat suggests in his comment -- `resultat.getvalue()`.